# MediaCodec as decoder to send decoded data to two surfaces. How can we avoid big trunk data copy?

Tags: android, surface

To configure a decoder, we call

`decoder.configure(format,surface, crypto,flags)`.

And then, in

`MediaCodec.Callback.onOutputBufferAvailable()`,

we call

`codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index,System.nanoTime())`

to draw the decoded video on that surface which is passed in configure() function. Do we have a way to send that output buffer to another surface which is created by an encoder from

`MediaCodec.createInputSurface()`

to avoid big trunk data copy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. After taking look into Nvidia Android source code and omx decoder implement; if we need to send data into two surfaces, we have to use native DMA memory copy functions from manufacturer, or using native omx decoder directly.